# Change cipher on open connection

Tags: c, ssl, networking, encryption, openssl

I'm developing a SSL-Cipher-Scanner. That means I specify host and port and my program tells me which ciphers the host accepts.

My current version works but is dead slow (about 20 to 30 sec per host) because I open up a new connection for each cipher.

I use the following methods (in this order):

```
ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ssl_ctx);
BIO_set_conn_port(bio, port);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, host);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, cipher);
BIO_do_connect(bio);
BIO_do_handshake(bio);
```

I now tried to just set the cipherlist again and do another handshake instead of connecting again. In wireshark I saw that it actually used the the change cipher spec protocol but that the server returned an encrypted alert (so I can't tell you which one it is). The return values of

```
SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, cipher);
```

and

```
BIO_do_handshake(bio);
```

are both 1 so it should be successful.

Could anyone please help me on how to change the used cipher on an open connection?

Some additional information: I use openssl version 1.0.2h

Comment: Checkout the source code for [sslscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/). It mostly does the same thing using OpenSSL, but at a different time in the workflow than you are trying. The original project was abandoned some time ago, but there are plenty of modern forks on GitHub.

Comment: The alert was encrypted in the old cipher suite, so you should be able to see what it was. It also suggests that the server didn't support the new cipher suite requested.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is very similar to a [renegotiation DOS attack](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2011/10/31/tls-renegotiation-and-denial-of-service-attacks). It is not uncommon that servers have limitations on how much renegotiations can be done. Typically none or only one renegotiation is allowed after the initial TLS handshake to defend against such DOS attack.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer! Do you have any suggestions for me on how I could aproach this? I mean the tool sslyze can do the scan in about 5-8 seconds on the same server and it has additional python overhead.

Comment: @Drilexus: start with `ALL` ciphers and then remove any cipher which succeeded. I.E. if you get first `AES-128` then your next cipher set is `ALL:!AES-128`. And once the connection fails you know that all relevant ciphers got checked.